# Mocking hhvm class methods with phpunit

Tags: mocking, phpunit, hhvm

I have been using HHVM with PHPUnit 5.3.*. I have had issues with mocking class methods using the `<?hh` syntax. It seems as though the syntax is not supported. Numerous `ReflectionException: Class Mock_{Classname} does not exist.

[image]

I imaging it is because of the hh syntax in the following method signature

```
 public function sendToAuthorizeNetForProcessing($client_billing_object,@\Repositories\Invoice $invoice
 ): @array<string, string> {
```

Are people using an alternative to mock classes with php-unit or another solution?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you need to run PHPUnit with hhvm

```
hhvm vendor/bin/phpunit tests
```